# svnant with --no-auth-cache option

Tags: svnant

Is there a way to use svn global command line options when using svnant?
Example option: ['--no-auth-cache'](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.tour.initial.disabling-password-caching)
We use javahl as svn lib.
[svnant documentation](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html) does not mention such options